# Is this some form of transposition?

Tags: c#, cryptography

I've been trying to develop a good transposition method for basic encryption (not going to be used in reality)

Does this fit the bill:

```
for (int k = 0; k < Plaintext.Length; k++) //transpose
{
     Swapchars(ResultArray, k, (key.length * k) % Plaintext.Length); 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know anything about the relation between `key.length` and `Plaintext.Length`?

Comment: If `key.length == int * plaintext.length`, this degenerates into a rotation by one.

Comment: more generally, if `plaintext.length` divides `key.length`, it seems to preserve blocks of `key.length` size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only uses the key length, not the key contents. So `"aaa"` and `"bbb"` as keys would encrypt the same way.

Here is a simple way to incorporate the key contents (note, that this code is of course educational. It is not real crypto):

```
var mulConstant = key.Sum(c => (int)c); //derive constant from key contents
for (int k = 0; k < Plaintext.Length; k++) //transpose
{
     Swapchars(ResultArray, k, (mulConstant * k) % Plaintext.Length); 
}
```

Instead of multiplying by `key.Length`, we use the sum of all key characters which depends on the whole key. When you change any char, the whole key changes.

There are still obvious weaknesses. The keys `"ab"` and `"ba"` would encrypt the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your comments :) this is being used with a substitution algorithm as well so the contents of the key didn't really matter but thank you for this as gives some confusion in the text.